# saxon distinct-values throws exception

Tags: java, xpath, saxon

I am trying to run a "distinct-values" XPath using Saxon. Here is my code:

```
 @Test
public void testAttributeSelect() throws XPathFactoryConfigurationException {
     System.setProperty("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:"
     + NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON,
     "net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl");
      System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory",
    "net.sf.saxon.dom.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
      String xpathString = "distinct-values(//id)";
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        System.out.println(builder.getClass());
        Document doc =
       builder.parse(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("parametrizedId_feed.xml"));
        System.out.println(doc.getClass());
        XPath xpath =
      XPathFactory.newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON).newXPath();

        NodeList s1 = (NodeList) 
        xpath.evaluate("/matches", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
       NodeList s = (NodeList) 
       xpath.evaluate(xpathString, s1 , XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I get this exception:

> javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: Cannot locate an object model implementation for nodes of class net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMNodeList
>       at net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:300)
>       at net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator.evaluate(XPathEvaluator.java:434)
>       at ca.cbc.panacea.playground.TestXpath.testAttributeSelect(TestXpath.java:43)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

Saxon-dom jar file is in the class path. 
Plus if I try to invoke the 'distinct-values' directly on doc object, I get a :

> net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Extension function required class org.w3c.dom.NodeList; supplied value of class net.sf.saxon.value.UntypedAtomicValue could not be converted
>       at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMObjectModel.convertXPathValueToObject(DOMObjectModel.java:395)
>       at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMObjectModel.access$000(DOMObjectModel.java:42)
>       at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMObjectModel$5.convert(DOMObjectModel.java:166)
>       at net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:352)
>       at net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator.evaluate(XPathEvaluator.java:434)

I cannot figure out what is going on here. And google doesn't either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First point to make is that DOM and Saxon don't go particularly well together. If you're constructing the tree in order to use Saxon on it, use Saxon's native tree model in preference to the DOM - it's ten times faster.

The fact that you mention saxon-dom.jar means you must be using a rather old version of Saxon, probably one that is no longer supported. So my next suggestion would be to move to a more recent release.

The other thing I noticed is that you asked for an XPath processor to work with the Saxon object model, and you then use it to work with the DOM object model. I don't know if that's likely to work or not. (If you want to be sure of loading Saxon rather than some other XPath engine, for example because you want XPath 2.0, then it's best to skip the JAXP factory mechanisms entirely and just instantiate the Saxon implementation directly.)

Comment: @arash:  To see code examples, one for using Saxon's native tree and one for using the DOM, goto http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.4/ then download the Saxon resources file.  Look in the "samples/java" folder for XPathExample.java and XPathExampleDOM.java.  These samples are helpful to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to retrieve the NodeList from Saxon.
After you execute your statement "List s = (List) xpath.evaluate(xpathString, doc1 , XPathConstants.NODESET);" you can use the code below to read the node and node value from List:

getTagValue("COMMODITYNAME", NodeOverNodeInfo.wrap((NodeInfo) s.get(i)))
"COMMODITYNAME" is the node in the XML the you want read the value and NodeOverNodeInfo.wrap((NodeInfo) s.get(i)) is the node currently pointing from "s" list.

private String getTagValue(String strag, NodeOverNodeInfo nodeInfo)
    {

```
    NodeList nodeList = nodeInfo.getChildNodes(); //list of  XML node
    Node nodeValue = null;
    String strReturn = null;
    for (int iItem=0;iItem<nodeList.getLength();iItem++)
    {
        nodeValue = nodeList.item(iItem).getFirstChild();   
        if (nodeValue != null && strag.equalsIgnoreCase(nodeValue.getParentNode().getNodeName()))
        {
            strReturn = nodeValue.getNodeValue();
            //punta la tag index
            //System.out.println(nodeValue.getParentNode().getNodeName()); //this is the node name
            //System.out.println(nodeValue.getNodeValue()); // this is the node value
        }
    }
return strReturn;
}
```

Bye,
Valerio

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, I just wanted to comment on Michael's response but commenting is very limited.
Thanks for the response Michael.
My dependencies are as follow:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.8</version>
        <classifier>xpath</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.0.8</version>
        <classifier>dom</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

AFAIK this is the latest in the maven repo. Please let me know if I miss something here. 
Your explanation of the situation was very good, except I need a sample code to figure out how to do all that.
I made the following changes, and it worked!

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("parametrizedId_feed.xml"));
         SAXSource ss = new SAXSource(is);

        XPath xpath =  XPathFactory.newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON).newXPath();
        NodeInfo doc1 = ((XPathEvaluator)xpath).setSource(ss);
        System.out.println("Loaded XPath Provider " + xpath.getClass().getName());

       List s = (List) xpath.evaluate(xpathString, doc1 , XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for(int i = 0 ; i<s.size(); i++){
            String n = (String) s.get(i);
            System.out.println(n);

        }
```

Is it what did you mean by saxon's Tree model?
The only problem is the evaluate method returns List instead of NodeList.
I want to mention that we moved to Saxon because of the superb speed and better functionality, so the codebase has many dependencies to the JAXP API, which is a hell to get ride of.

Comment: Any version of Saxon that you find in a Maven repository is unofficial and unauthorised, and it probably does not contain the statutory notices which are required by the licensing terms for third-party components such as the Unicode library. The current version of Saxon is 9.4. Yes, NodeInfo is a node in Saxon's tree model. The NodeList class is specific to DOM, and you will only get a NodeList back if you are processing a DOM. (I'm afraid the JAXP spec is very messy when processing models other than DOM, and I would recommend Saxon's s9api API in preference.)